# Current state of js controlled video playback on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, video, html5-video

I'm making an HTML website. What I try to achieve is to delay video playback a little bit from the user action in order to play some animation before the video starts. I know that video playback on iOS and Android must be tied to the user action, so you can't autoplay it. However it seems that you also can't set a delay on user initiated playback - is that correct or is there any way to do it other than setting timeout?

Also from what I see (on iOS at least) the limitation is not lifted after initial user initiated playback. So if you play and pause video you still can't resume it without user action. Is this also correct?

**EDIT**

Ok, one workaround feasible in some scenarios would be to hide the video instead of pausing it and then seek to 0 instead of unpausing but since you also can't change the volume programmatically this makes sense only on silent videos.

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting article regarding **Safari 10** (Just on iOS 10?):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH11-DontLinkElementID_12

**Inline and Auto Video Playback in iOS:**

> On iOS, videos without audio tracks or with disabled audio tracks can
>   play automatically when the webpage loads.
>
> When the -playsinline- property is specified, Safari on iPhone allows
>   videos to play inline. Videos without the property will commence
>   playback in fullscreen, but users can pinch close on the video to
>   continue playing the video inline.

Comment: And how would that help to delay the video playback?

Comment: That is useful for mute videos, but in case of those the trick with hiding and seeking works as well.